# Sencha - How call controller method by returned New Ext.Button

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Bellow code was result of searching for it in Stackoverflow and finding this:

[How to add button in Grid view column in extjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995469/how-to-add-button-in-grid-view-column-in-extjs)

but as turns out its generating some problems for which I cannot find answer ;(.

So, what I need to do is to have grid which contain data like: taskId,task StartTimestamp,task EndTimestamp, result(this can be displayed actualy as task status("pending","error","rejected") and for status "done" I need actually to display a button as its described bellow in code which after clicking on it fire up method to generate pdf).

I have MVC structure as:

view is defined as Ext.define('MyApp.meta.requests.view.MetaRequests'{some stuff}, and inside I have declared controller as follows controller: 'metaRequests', wchich is declared as Ext.define('MyApp.meta.requests.controller.MetaRequestsController', {some stuff}

if I try to call any method from controller in button which looks like:

```
renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
    var status = record.get('status');
    if (status === 'DONE') {
         var id = Ext.id();
         Ext.defer(function(){
            new Ext.Button({
                padding: 0,
                text: 'PDF',
                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-download',
                **handler :** 'loadMetaRequests'
            }).render(document.body, id);
         },50);
         return Ext.String.format('<div id="{0}"></div>', id);
    }
    if (status === 'QUEUED') {
        metaData.tdCls = 'queued-status';
        return status;
    }
    if (status === 'PENDING') {
        metaData.tdCls = 'pending-status';
        return status;
    }
    if (status === 'REJECTED') {
        metaData.tdCls = 'reject-status';
        metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + Ext.String.htmlEncode(record.get('errorMessages')) + '"';
        return status;
    }
    if (status === 'ERROR') {
        metaData.tdCls = 'error-status';
        return status;
    }
}
```

clicking on buttun will generate error as follows (and of course other elements calling method from controller without problem so I thing that here cane be problem with the scope which I cannot grasp somehow):

```
ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:2585 Uncaught Error: No method named "loadMetaRequests" on Ext.button.Button
    at new Ext.Error (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:2585)
    at Function.raise (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:2644)
    at Object.Ext.raise (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:2723)
    at Object.callback (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:8481)
    at constructor.fireHandler (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:133044)
    at constructor.onClick (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:133032)
    at constructor.fire (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:20326)
    at constructor.fire (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:32699)
    at constructor.publish (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:32675)
    at constructor.doDelegatedEvent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:32725)
Ext.Error @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:2585
raise @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:2644
Ext.raise @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:2723
callback @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:8481
fireHandler @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:133044
onClick @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:133032
fire @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:20326
fire @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:32699
publish @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:32675
doDelegatedEvent @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:32725
onDelegatedEvent @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:32712
(anonymous) @ ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20180323101627:6696
```

I would be appreciated for any help possible on how to actualy call method from this controller.

Comment: The question/answer you found is for extjs4, and there were interesting improvements in ExtJS 6. If I were you, I'd have a look at the [`widgetcolumn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html) component.

Comment: Unfortunetly I do not see how this widgetcolumn could really help me (by reading example in docs)... As usual I'll end up using some new fancy sencha functionality but it would require to do more walkarounds and wasting time to it than doing something simple. I need simple thing ... or show text - status or show button that run method.

Answer (score 0):

Your Button is in the browser window scope, but the controller isn't defined and/or loaded in that scope.

If you supply the grid (the MetaRequests object/the parent of the render function's scope) where your controller is mentioned and required as a third argument to the Ext.Defer function you should get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Workaround:

```
     var controller = this.controller;
     Ext.defer(function(){
         new Ext.Button({
             padding: 0,
             text: 'PDF',
             iconCls: 'x-fa fa-download',
             controller:controller,
             handler :function(){this.controller.loadMetaRequests();}
         }).render(document.body, id);
     },50);
```

A little dirty but it works